# UNSET not working for Zend Session

Tags: php, zend-framework, session, zend-session, zend-session-namespace

I'm working with **Zend Session** but I have a problem. If I instanciate a `Zend_Session_Namespace('a')` and unset it, I continue getting the storage:

```
$storage = new Zend_Session_Namespace('a');
unset($storage);
$storage = new Zend_Session_Namespace('a');
echo $storage->id;
```

**And get the data I stored before.**

Any idea???

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```
$storage->unsetAll();
```

Or this for a single value:

```
unset($storage->id);
```